# What name, format, and scheme should be chosen in order to "factory reset" a MacBook Pro?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, disk-format, macbook-pro

I am following [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065) and during step 7 ([Erase your hard drive and reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208496)), the fourth step is "Click Erase, then complete these items: Name .. Format .. Scheme ..".

In order to emulate a "Factory Reset" of the MacBook Pro (so I can get its state as close as possible to when it arrived from the Apple factory), what are the defaults for all 3 of these options?

[image]

Comment: I always say “there’s no such thing as a factory reset of a computer” because unlike a phone where for all practicality, you cannot wipe a phone and install another OS or dual boot like like a computer, nobody wants an out of date computer.  If you were to “factory reset” a 2014 Mac, you’d be installing Yosemite.  If you want to sell it, you know you potential customers are looking for the ability to run the latest and greatest.  So, the answer to this question  is - it depends. What’s the Mac you’re looking to sell/give away so you can determine what’s the latest and greatest OS supported..

Answer (score 1):

If you're intending to reinstall macOS on the disk at some point (which 99% of people would be), then use these:

**Name**

> Enter a name for the disk: 'Macintosh HD' is the default on a new Mac

**Format**

> use APFS for formatting, and

**Scheme**

> GUID Partition Map for scheme

#### Notes

[This source](https://9to5mac.com/2020/07/02/how-to-factory-reset-macbook-pro/) recommends using 'Mac OS Extended (Journaled)' format. BUT if you want to be able to reinstall macOS (who doesn't?), then **you must reformat to APFS**, otherwise you'll get a message like

> This Mac can only install macOS on APFS-formatted drives. Please use Disk Utility to reformat as APFS